# Removing elements before and after a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, dependencies

I start from a list that looks like this:

```
['package1:', 'package2:', 'package1,', 'package2', '|', 'package4', 'package3:', 'package2', '|', 'package1,', 'package3']
```

Since i'm working with dependencies and the `|` means `or`, when i find one i create a sublist so that i can work on it later.

For now the output look like this:

```
['package1:', 'package2:', 'package1,', 'package2', ['package2', 'package4'], 'package4', 'package3:', 'package2', ['package2', 'package1,'], 'package1,', 'package3']
```

but it should look like this:

```
['package1:', 'package2:', 'package1,', ['package2', 'package4'], 'package3:', ['package2', 'package1,'], 'package3']
```

The point is that my code when finds a `|` is already to late, because the element before is already added and also don't jump the next element, because is a loop ( basically the element before and after the `|` ).

my code is this:

```
for element in range(len(raw_text)):
temp_list=[]
flag = False

if raw_text[element] == '|':
    temp_list.append(raw_text[element-1]), temp_list.append(raw_text[element+1])
    flag = True
if raw_text[element].endswith('') and raw_text[element] != '|':
    text.append(raw_text[element])
if flag == True:
    text.append(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
text = []
i = 0
while True:
    if i > len(raw_text)-2:
        # No more possible |'s, so wrap things up
        text.append( raw_text[-1] )
        break
    if raw_text[i+1] == '|':
        # Add the items around the |; move past the group
        text.append( [raw_text[i], raw_text[i+2]] )
        i += 3
    else:
        # Add the current element & move on
        text.append( raw_text[i] )
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `del` so something like `del text[3]` to remove an item from the list. So in your `if flag == True:` just add something like `del text[-1]` to remove the last element added, then append your new list and then skip or just don't add the next item.

Another option would be to change

```
if flag == True:
    text.append(temp_list)
```

to

```
if flag == True:
    text[-1] = temp_list
```

and then skip the next element in the list.